# Android application developed with android API is not working pefectly with google API

Tags: android, google-api

My application that connects a database via network, The application will do some login and registration procedures as normal, The app is working fine with AVD targeting ANDROID API, But when i Changed to Google API-8, Im nota able to communicate with network.

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Comment: A google API emulator uses the exact same SDK as the Android API emulator. It simple has some extra services, like Google Maps.

Comment: error handled in the project and iam toasting an error message "unable to connect network", The problem is :- Application is unable to communicate over network

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved by changing API to 17